# Pandas to_sql error - 'Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to push a pandas dataframe to an existing sqlite database. I am getting the following error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I would like to push the pandas dataframe to a new table in the database. The code is as follows:

```
data.to_sql(name=data, con=database.db,
             if_exists='append', index_label='record_identifier', chunksize=10000)
```

All series in the dataframe are 'object' type.

Help understanding and fixing the error would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Data representation. NB: I can push this to SQL but it is a reasonable representation of the data (some string IDs and text). Happy to edit with further tests.

```
ex_dic = {
'id': ['ID-1', 'ID-2', 'ID-3'],
'color': ['red', 'blue', 'red']
}

columns = ['id', 'color']
index = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df = pd.DataFrame(ex_dic, columns=columns, index=index)
```

Datatypes being used (data.dtypes):

```
record_identifier       object
stem_notes_1            object
stem_notes_2            object
stem_notes_3            object
stem_notes_4            object
stem_notes_5            object
stem_notes_6            object
stem_notes_7            object
stem_combined_notes     object
dtype: object
```

Comment: The definition of data ie `data = pd.DataFrame(...)` would be useful here

Comment: We'll need to see the frame definition to see what types are being inserted.

Comment: Just added the dataframe dtypes - is this what you mean?

Comment: Use an [SQLAlchemy engine connection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlite) and not raw DB-API connection for migrating pandas data.